# How to prove if function is right or left inverse in concise manner?

Tags: functions, inverse

Here's the question:

> Let $f: D \rightarrow Z$ be a function.
>
> Show that: if function $g: Z \rightarrow D$ is given with charateristic:
>
> $$\forall z \in Z: f(g(z)) = z$$
>
> then $f$ is surjective.

My Proof:
I just tried to prove this using definition of bijection of a function.

Firstly $\Rightarrow$:

It is already given that $\forall z \in Z: f(g(z)) = z$. So that means $g$ is bijective.
That means that $\forall z \in Z, x \in D: g(z) = x$. In other words every $z$ in Pre-Image has atmost one image in $D$. So it is injective. Also $\forall x \in D$ there exists also a Pre-Image, which means its surjective.

Now $g$ is bijective. That means $f: D \rightarrow Z$ is inverse of $g$.

Therefore $f(x) = z$ and as $g(z) = x$ then $f(g(z) = z$ is obviously true.

So we can say that $f$ is sujective?

Or is there any concise way of proving it?

Comment: "It is already given that $\forall z \in Z: f(g(z)) = z$. So that means $g$ is bijective".This statement is false,this means only that $g$ is injective.

Comment: Then how come does $g$ have inverse $f$?

Comment: What is truly strange about this problem: Here is a real and complete proof that $f$ is **sur**jective: "$\forall z \in Z, f(g(z)) = z$, thus $f$ is surjective."

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I figured it out.

$f$ is bijective.

$g$ is bijective because

$$∀∈:(())=$$

so that means there for every $x \in D$ there exists one and only one $z \in Z$ for function $f$.
Other way round, for all $z \in Z$ there exists pre-Image in $x \in D$.

Comment: Consider: $Z = D = \Bbb R$, $$\begin{align}f(x) &= \begin{cases}0,& x =k\pi\text{ for some }k \in \Bbb Z\\\cot x,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\g(x) &= \text{Arc}\,\text{cot } x\end{align}$$ $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, but $f$ is not a bijection, and neither is $g$.